# javascript clearInterval() function is not working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, intervals, clearinterval

```js
   var a = 0;

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
 
  clearInterval(interval) //this dont work
  var interval = setInterval(function() { //this is good
    if (a == 0) {
      console.log(a);
      a = 10;
    } else if (a == 10) {
      console.log(a);
    }
  }, 120)
})
```

//I want when user press key interval stop , than new interval start again but old interval cant stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems.

- You have `var interval` **inside** your function so it gets **reset** every time the function runs.
- `setTimeout` will call a function, once, after a time period. It won't clear an interval, you need `clearInterval` for that.

Comment: You have to fix both problems, not just one of them.

Comment: can you change my code and post in comments?

Comment: i do evrything you said but still dont work

Comment: You still have `var interval` inside your function.

Comment: if i change var with let or const iam getting error

Comment: Because you are still declaring the variable **inside** the function! The emphasis in the answer was on the "inside" part of declaring it, not the keyword you used to do so.

Comment: but it must be in function if i want to do this, can you change code and post in comment

Comment: It **can't** be in the function to do that. Declare it outside the function. Assign a value to it inside the function.

Comment: Thanks bro. my bad you said good but i am soo stupid.